# Included container does't work with docker compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose, hdfs

I have Kafka/Zookeeper container and Divolte container in - https://github.com/divolte/docker-divolte/blob/master/docker-compose.yml, which correctly starts and works by

```
docker-compose up -d --build
```

I want to add the hdfs container -  https://hub.docker.com/r/mdouchement/hdfs/ which correctly starts and works by

```
docker run -p 22022:22 -p 8020:8020 -p 50010:50010 -p 50020:50020 -p 50070:50070 -p 50075:50075 -it mdouchement/hdfs
```

But after adding the code to yml:

```
  hdfs:
    image: mdouchement/hdfs
    environment:
      DIVOLTE_KAFKA_BROKER_LIST: kafka:9092
    ports:
      - "22022:22"
      - "8020:8020"
      - "50010:50010"
      - "50020:50020"
      - "50070:50070"
      - "50075:50075"
    depends_on:
      - kafka
```

The web http://localhost:50070 and data node http://localhost:8020/ did not answer. Could you help me to add new container? Which of hdfs ports do I have to write as source connection port?

The logs of HDFS container is:

```
2020-02-21T15:11:47.613270635Z Starting OpenBSD Secure Shell server: sshd.
2020-02-21T15:11:50.440130986Z Starting namenodes on [localhost]
2020-02-21T15:11:54.616344960Z localhost: Warning: Permanently added 'localhost' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.
2020-02-21T15:11:54.616369660Z localhost: starting namenode, logging to /opt/hadoop/logs/hadoop-root-namenode-278b399bc998.out
2020-02-21T15:11:59.328993612Z localhost: Warning: Permanently added 'localhost' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.
2020-02-21T15:11:59.329016212Z localhost: starting datanode, logging to /opt/hadoop/logs/hadoop-root-datanode-278b399bc998.out
2020-02-21T15:12:06.078269195Z Starting secondary namenodes [0.0.0.0]
2020-02-21T15:12:10.837364362Z 0.0.0.0: Warning: Permanently added '0.0.0.0' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.
2020-02-21T15:12:10.839375064Z 0.0.0.0: starting secondarynamenode, logging to /opt/hadoop/logs/hadoop-root-secondarynamenode-278b399bc998.out
2020-02-21T15:12:17.249040842Z starting portmap, logging to /opt/hadoop/logs/hadoop--portmap-278b399bc998.out
2020-02-21T15:12:18.253954832Z DEPRECATED: Use of this script to execute hdfs command is deprecated.
2020-02-21T15:12:18.253993233Z Instead use the hdfs command for it.
2020-02-21T15:12:18.254002633Z
2020-02-21T15:12:21.277829129Z starting nfs3, logging to /opt/hadoop/logs/hadoop--nfs3-278b399bc998.out
2020-02-21T15:12:22.284864146Z DEPRECATED: Use of this script to execute hdfs command is deprecated.
2020-02-21T15:12:22.284883446Z Instead use the hdfs command for it.
2020-02-21T15:12:22.284887146Z
```

Port description:

```
Ports
Portmap -> 111
NFS -> 2049
HDFS namenode -> 8020 (hdfs://localhost:8020)
HDFS datanode -> 50010
HDFS datanode (ipc) -> 50020
HDFS Web browser -> 50070
HDFS datanode (http) -> 50075
HDFS secondary namenode -> 50090
SSH -> 22
```

The docker-compose response answer is:

```
                   Name                                 Command               State                                             Ports
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
divolte-streamsets-quickstart_divolte_1      /opt/divolte/start.sh            Up       0.0.0.0:8290->8290/tcp
divolte-streamsets-quickstart_hdfs_1         /bin/sh -c service ssh sta ...   Exit 0
divolte-streamsets-quickstart_kafka_1        supervisord -n                   Up       2181/tcp, 9092/tcp, 9093/tcp, 9094/tcp, 9095/tcp, 9096/tcp, 9097/tcp, 9098/tcp, 9099/tcp
divolte-streamsets-quickstart_streamsets_1   /docker-entrypoint.sh dc -exec   Up       0.0.0.0:18630->18630/tcp
```

Comment: Please show your container logs for the hdfs process... Also, is that container running both a namenode and a datanode?

Comment: Also, there's no reason hdfs should depend on kafka. It's the other way around. Similarly, DIVOLTE_KAFKA_BROKER_LIST means nothing to the hdfs container

Comment: Deleted the environment and added HDFS container logs to question.

Comment: I think yes, the container work  running both a namenode and a datanode, added port description.

Comment: Are you able to run  `docker exec hdfs jps`?

Comment: Error response from daemon: Container 278b399bc99879ead132d58efcd33b4494c3349ab7574d744fa7298fa62c1b53 is not running

Comment: And the state is - Exit 0

Comment: Well, there you go. It's not starting

Comment: Personally, I use these https://github.com/big-data-europe/docker-hadoop

Comment: @cricket_007 Thank you. Could you write pls whats better: to use docker-hadoop project and add kafka and devolt containers or add containers from docker-hadoop to my project.

Comment: I've never used devolt... I'm just saying that 1) namenode and datanode should be separate. 2) You don't really need a ResourceManager or NodeManager 3) getting Hadoop alone working then adding Kafka, and finally setting up the collector would be my recommendation

Comment: @cricket_007 Wow, Its work. thank you. Move pls your recommendations to answer.